# Defining params at top-level in layer chart gives duplicate signal error

Tags: vega-lite

Adding signal/params at top-level gives duplicate signal error.
Please refer the following gist: https://vega.github.io/editor/#/gist/707bfd917262898f155acf1d6e50fff4/root_signal_layer_spec.json

Specifying params at layer level works fine.
But, need the signal to be updated via Vega View API which has access only to the top-level params. so, was trying to move the params to top-level.
Is there any restriction that top-level params are not allowed in layer composition spec or any workaround for this workflow?

Answer (score 0):

When you try to provide params at top level, then you get the `duplicate signal error`. This is because the vega-lite is probably assuming that the 2 layers should have same params, so its trying to create 2 params with same name. But the params `name` should be unique as per the [document](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/parameter.html#defining-a-parameter).

Instead you should provide the params at layer-level as you tried before. Also you mentioned that you are trying to update the signal using Vega View API, so this should work just fine because each param name is unique throughout the whole view.

You can simply access your signal using `VEGA_DEBUG.view.signal('rootSignal')`.
Refer document https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/api/view/#view_signal.

Just to check if your param name exists as signal or not, when provided on layer level. Try using `VEGA_DEBUG.view._signals.rootSignal`

Comment: After moving "params" to layer level, able to access the signals using VEGA_DEBUG.view.signal. Now, with only layer spec no issues. 

[Updated spec](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/gist/167fe9cbf1ff01a5d347a8cfbeedfc17/root_signal_layer_spec_v1.json) to add one filter and dynamically updating it using view API

Command to update selection using Vega view API:
`VEGA_DEBUG.view.signal("rootSignal_tuple", {"unit":"","fields":[{"type":"E","field":"month_date","channel":"x"}],"values":[1341081000000]}).runAsync()`

Comment: Its working right ? or you are facing any other issue ?

Comment: But it's not working if layer spec is specified inside "facet". In this case, am not seeing the signals at the root level like `rootSignal_tuple`. 
[Spec with layer inside facet](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/gist/6b04437000b38e115a76c8fa65b4d630/facet_layer_spec_update_nested_signal.json)

Now `VEGA_DEBUG.view.signal("rootSignal_tuple")` gives an error with unrecognised signal name. Any work-around in this case?

Comment: In case of "facet", see the signal is available under "subcontext". Does Vega view has an API to update signals at subcontext. Can see the signals from `VEGA_DEBUG.view.getState()['subcontext'][4]['signals']['rootSignal_tuple']` but if I try to update that signal and again use setState() it's not reflecting

Comment: There is a `signal viewer` section below the chart view. In that section, am not seeing the `rootSignal_tuple` which was there without the facet chart. I don't know the reason why its not available in case of `facet`. Lets wait for more credible answer on this.